What is truth according to Plato and Hegel?
Socrates and Plato used dialectics in order to show fallacies. From what I understand, Plato went even further than Socrates, for him truth was something reached at the limit of dialectics.
Hegel's view on truth seems similar to Plato's -- truth is at the end of the Hegelian dialectic. Basically, once we are done resolving all the contradictions, we are going to reach the truth.
Was truth for both Plato and Hegel an ideal that can't actually be reached. For example, if I were to give a proposition X and claim it to be true, would both of them have denied the existence of such thing?

For Plato, the truth is what we once knew and then forgot, see Anamnesis, dialectics is the way to unforget and the truth is reachable. Hegel's dialectic is more ambitious, it does not just help us unforget. In some sense, our reason shapes the truth about the world through dialectics because the same reason is operative in the world itself, see SEP, Why does Hegel use dialectics?

@Conifold, so for Hegel the proposition X is true relative to this "thinking episode", but it is not true absolutely?

"Thinking episodes" of all of humanity (and other rational beings, if any) through all of history link up into one grand dialectics of what Hegel calls Geist or "Absolute Spirit" that shapes and cognizes the truth. There is no "relative truth", but there is limited comprehension of it accessible to a finite being at some stage of history.

For Plato, see e.g. Sophist, 263b:

Stranger: Now what quality shall be ascribed to each of these sentences? Theaetetus: One is false, I suppose, the other true.


Stranger: The true one states facts as they are about you. Theaetetus: Certainly.


Stranger: And the false one states things that are other than the facts.

This, truth/false are "qualities" of sentences and a true sentence is one that "states facs" while a false sentence is one that "states things that are other than the facts".
See e.g. Blake E. Hestir, Plato on the Metaphysical Foundation of Meaning and Truth (Cambridge University Press, 2016).
For Hegel, see e.g. Tal Meir Giladi, Hegel's Truth: A Property of Things? (2022):

In his Encyclopaedia Logic, Hegel affirms that truth is ‘usually’ understood as the agreement of thought with the object, but that in the ‘deeper, i.e. philosophical sense’, truth is the agreement of a content with itself or of an object with its concept.


It sounds like he subscribed to the correspondence theory of truth?

@spacemonkey - IMO we cannot find a more precise theory of truth prior to Aristotle, that in Met defines what truth is. Prior to that, we may speak of a "common sense" view of truth/false.

@MauroALLEGRANZA What do you think can be derived from Parmenides' fragments - long before Aristotle - about his conception of truth?  "Ἀλήθεια" is a key term in his work. - I was rather impressed when reading for the first time the Parmenides edition by Ernst Heitsch, Tusculum 1974 (Introduction and commentary in German). Heitsch even interprets B VIII, 16 of Parmenides' fragments as the discovery of the law of excluded middle.

@JoWehler - quite complex... P's Poem: "It is necessary to say and to think that What Is is; for it is to be,/ but nothing it is not. These things I bid you ponder. (Fr.6)" He speaks of being: "what is" and "For this shall never be proved, that the things that are not are."

@MauroALLEGRANZA Yes, that's the idea of Heitsch' interpretation: Parmenides exemplified the law of excluded middle with the example of "being", because he could not yet state the general abstract formalized version of the law of excluded middle. - I do not know wheter any classical philologist later took up Heitsch' interpretation of Parmenides VIII,16.


Following the comment by @Conifold: Plato considers truth to be one
exemplar from the domain of forms or ideas. Plato designs the domain
of forms as a trancendent domain. Other forms are beauty, justice,
and goodness.

The ontological status of goodness is left unclear. Though the idea of godness is
basic for the other ideas, it is decribed only in a metaphorical
way. Plato compares the role of goodness in the realm of ideas to
the role of the sun in our mundane domain. For more detail see
Plato, The Republic. Book VI, Section 508a-509b.

Plato used his theory of forms to explain how we recognize that
certain human behaviour, institutions, statements  or just human
things have the corresponding property, i.e. why they are beautiful,
just or true. That’s the doctrine of anamnesis: The term“refers to
the recollection of innate knowledge acquired before birth.” , see
Anamnesis.
Socrates speech
in Plato’s “Symposion” elaborates on this method applied to the idea
of beauty. For a more mundane discussion see also Plato’s “Menon”.

The crucial presupposition of Plato's whole theory of forms: Before
birth the individual soul went around in the domain of forms and
engraving on itself each form - walking around as if in a museum, contemplating each different form presented on a pedestal. Later in real life the
encorporated soul just remembers
It is possible to translate Plato’s theory to a modern setting, using
the concepts of phylogenesis and ontogenesis. Nevertheless the
whole doctrine remains questionable as a poetical metaphor, without
the capacity to explain any real phenomena. Not to speak about the
possibility to check it.
Therefore I do not see, that Plato's theory helps to find out synthetical true statements about our world and to verify their truthness.


Unfortunately, I am not competent to make any comments about Hegel’s abstract concept of truth.
